# how to check the status of bus (in state joined ) using wsadmin command

Tags: jython

I am using the below command to get the details of buses. How can I check for state joined?

```
wsadmin>MEList=AdminControl.queryNames('type=SIBMessagingEngine,*').split('lineseparator')
```

Comment: folks,

How I can get current status for buses (in state joined)? 
I know, that I can use AdminControl.queryNames('type=SIBMessagingEngine,*').split('lineseparator')[0] to check that buses are started or not.
But for state joined no idea please help.

Answer (score 0):

JMX scripting will do.

```
me = AdminControl.queryNames('WebSphere:*,type=SIBMessagingEngine').splitlines()
```

Let's say you want to check the first ME

```
wsadmin>meObject = AdminControl.makeObjectName(me[0])
wsadmin>AdminControl.invoke_jmx(meObject, 'isStarted', [], [])
1
wsadmin>AdminControl.invoke_jmx(meObject, 'state', [], [])
'Started'
```

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2FmbeanDocs%2Findex.html